# How to launch cmd running a command from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I want to write a powershell script that sets up a development environment. Firstly, I want to launch two command prompts which are running `yarn run dev:client` and `yarn run dev:server` respectively.

I have tried `start cmd` and `Start-Process cmd -Argument yarn,run,dev:server`, but am unable to get the newly launched command prompt to run the command.

How do I do this?

Comment: CMD /K "<INSERT_COMMAND_HERE>" so ie. Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/K "echo Hi!"'

Comment: What does "unable to get the newly launched command prompt to run the command" mean? The `cmd.exe` window opens but the command doesn't run? The `cmd.exe` window doesn't open?

Answer (score 1):

The generic way is:
`cmd /c "insert_your_command_here"`

This means in your case you would execute:

```
cmd /c "yarn run dev:client"
cmd /c "yarn run dev:server"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$arg="run dev:server"
Start-Process -FilePath path_to_yarn  -Args $arg -passthru -RedirectStandardError err.log
```